# openbravo 3.0 erp - how to work with source code for customization

Tags: openbravo

I am using `openbravo 3.0 erp` (free version) for customization.I need to modify the Physical Inventory screen(Application->Warehouse Management->Transaction->Physical Inventory).I have successfully run the openbravo 3.0 erp in my localhost.

My problem is I am unable to find out the view page of the Physical Inventory screen.I am new to this.Can any one help me to find the view name?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical Inventory file may available in `"openbravo_home/srcAD/org/openbravo/erpWindows/PhysicalInventory"`

Remember Openbravo is using Application dictionary to develop windows.So you need to use templates to modify this window.(don't do direct edit,it may overrriden during build)

```
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Development_Project_Structure#src-wad
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_change_an_existing_Window
http://thirumalaik.blogspot.in/
```